# contextual conversation in chat bot using python

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

So I am making a chat bot. Things like Intent classification,entity extraction and dialog generation are almost done.The conversations are stateless and now i am stuck at implementing context in conversation(meaning chat bot can remember what the user said and respond accordingly ).

Is there any python library to do that?
If not can anyone guide me how can i do that?

I want the context management to be almost same as IBM Watson Conversation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

At the present time, deep learning is the state of the art and [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) is the great technology to take advantage of deep learning.

[This](https://chatbotsmagazine.com/contextual-chat-bots-with-tensorflow-4391749d0077) is an amazing chatbot framework to build a conversational model for your custom chat bot. You should edit this [JSON file](https://github.com/ugik/notebooks/blob/master/intents.json) to create your conversational intents. Moreover, you can edit the JSON file dynamically according to user's messages or information which are shared by user. You can create and develop an architecture for it so you can reach the stateless conversation system.

For example, you  can analyze each messages of users by [NLP](http://www.nltk.org/) and update the JSON file.

As a summary, you can develop an architecture by using [this chatbot framework](https://chatbotsmagazine.com/contextual-chat-bots-with-tensorflow-4391749d0077) to create the stateless conversation system.